# Livewire data tables can't access public property

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm working with Livewire Datatables (https://github.com/mediconesystems/livewire-datatables)

In my component, I have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Job;
use Mediconesystems\LivewireDatatables\Http\Livewire\LivewireDatatable;
use Mediconesystems\LivewireDatatables\Column;
use Mediconesystems\LivewireDatatables\NumberColumn;
use Mediconesystems\LivewireDatatables\DateColumn;

class JobsTable extends LivewireDatatable
{
    public $model = Job::class;

    public function columns()
    {
        return [
            Column::checkbox(),
            NumberColumn::name('id')->label('ID')
                ->linkTo('cl/jobs/edit'),
            Column::name('Entry_id')->label('Entry ID')
                ->defaultSort('asc')->filterable(),
            Column::name('state')
                ->label('State')->filterable(),

            Column::name('title')
                ->label('Title'),

            Column::name('description')
                ->label('Description')->truncate(),
        ];
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.jobs-table');
    }
    public function store()
    {
    }
}
```

In my routing, I'm calling this as a full page component:

```
Route::get('/cl/jobs', JobsTable::class);
```

Everything is there, but the component doesn't actually render. It only renders the default content from app.blade.php.

If I add the {{slot}} variable to my jobs-table blade file, I get an saying it does not exist. I can see in the debug bar that component is loading, but not rendering to the page.

**Updated**
Based on feedback, I tried getting it to render to a custom slot:
'''        return view('livewire.jobs-table')->layout('livewire.jobs-table')->slot('JobsTable');
'''

Then in the blade file:

```
                {{  $JobsTable }}
            </main>
```

I still get an error, telling me that $JobsTable is not defined.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luXJT.png)

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does your view look like? You don't use a slot in the Livewire view, only the layout

Comment: In your Blade you call $JobsTable. But in the componente you have only declared $model.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that you have a seperate löayout for this component. Take a look what layouts you have. and then try to assign the layout with `->layout('layouts.job-layout');`in your render funktion.

```
public function render() 
{
    return view('livewire.jobs-table')->layout('layouts.job-layout');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but unfortunately I still get the error "undefined variable slot"

Comment: @DavidHamilton ok. try instead `{{  $JobsTable } </main>`in your blade {{ $model }}